# iMacros Extract data from XML document

Tags: xml, imacros

I have an XML document from Google API.

I tried using

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

No success.

How do I extract data from such documents?

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with the source. Something like that:

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"([\\s\\S]*)" EXTRACT=$1
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```